# AngularJS $scope not populating view

Tags: angularjs

I have a view like so:

```
<div ng-controller= "test" ng-init = "doit()">
    <span>{{testval}}</span>
</div>
```

The view's controller looks like this:

```
function test($scope){
    var counter = 0;
    $scope.doit = function(){
       console.log('switched to view');
       $scope.testval = counter++; 
    };
};
```

The first time I switch to the view controlled by 'test', it shows '0'.  After that, it shows nothing, but the console.log continues firing.   How can I set this up to execute 'doit' each time I switch to the view and successfully update the view by modifying $scope?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to add `$scope.digest()` to the end of `doit`.  The example listed is a boiled down example of the logic I was encountering on a much smaller scale.  In reality, it was a function called `getPhysOrd` that executed an asynchronous templated websocket bridge to query data off the server.  It had to be able to do this on-the-fly.  Calling digest forced the watchers to update the view according to the model changes.  Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Remove the ng-init() and put the call to doit() into your controller:

```
function test($scope){
    var counter = 0;
    $scope.doit = function(){
       console.log('switched to view');
       $scope.testval = counter++; 
    };
    $scope.doit();
};
```

Each time you switch to this view, the controller code will execute.
If you want the counter to persist between view changes, you'll have to put it into a service or $rootScope (because the controller, well its $scope, is destroyed when you move to another view).

Comment: I thought the controller was instantiated as an object?  I want to be able to call "doit" dynamically and on-the-fly from within the view.

Comment: @Andrew, when ng-controller is encountered in the HTML (or when ng-view is used and a route specifies which controller to create for that route, and you switch to that route) Angular creates a new scope and then "applies (in the sense of JavaScript's Function#apply) the controller constructor function" to the new scope object.  So is there also a controller object?  It is not clear to me if there is or not.